# Functions with returns 'table' has no begin...end?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I ever add 'Begin' after 'As' It says incorrect syntax. It works just fine If I'm trying to return one value though.

Instead I should add 'return' after 'as' and open brackets ()

Why is that?

**With one value as returns, I can do it fine:**

```
 CREATE FUNCTION MATHEE(@A int,@B int)
 returns int
 as 
 begin
    DECLARE @C int

    SET @C = @A + @B

 return @C 
 end
```

**With table as returns, I cant:**

```
   CREATE FUNCTION TOP_USERSs(@number int,@bob varchar(20))
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
BEGIN

RETURN SELECT agent from Agents where agent = @bob and prime > @number
END
```

**It says :**

> Incorrect syntax near 'BEGIN'.

It works fine using brackets and without begin..end though:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TOP_USERSs(@number int,@bob varchar(20))
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN
(
 SELECT agent from Agents where agent = @bob and prime > @number
)
```

Comment: You need to show the failing SQL.

Comment: @AlexK. added. I did these exampls assuming that both syntax to return one value or a whole table are the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`RETURNS TABLE` in an *Inline User-Defined Function* & these do not have function bodies

> [There is no function_body delimited by BEGIN and END.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189294(v=sql.105).aspx)

For example if you added `set @number += 1` before the `RETURN` this would also fail to parse.

Answer (score 7):

`RETURNS TABLE` creates an inline table-valued function. It supposed to have a single `select` wrapped in `return` as its body:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TOP_USERSs(@number int,@bob varchar(20))
returns table
as return (
    select ...
);
```

If you want the begin-end syntax, that is a multi-statement table-valued function, and you will then need to declare the table it returns:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TOP_USERSs(@number int,@bob varchar(20))
returns @result table (agent varchar(10) not null)
as
begin
    insert into @result (agent) ... ;
    ...
    return;
end;
```

Comment: The return in the second query will automatically return the table without the need to mention 'return @result' ?

Comment: @Dablackninja The contract is that the returned data is whatever is contained in `@result` at the point of exiting from the function. `Return` simply performs the exit.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare fields of Return table as following code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TOP_USERSs(@number int,@bob varchar(20))
RETURNS @Result TABLE ( Agent varchar(20) )
AS
BEGIN
    Insert into @Result 
    SELECT agent from Agents where agent = @bob and prime > @number

    RETURN 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql), there are two kinds of table-valued function, with different syntaxes:

> ```
> -- Transact-SQL Inline Table-Valued Function Syntax   
> CREATE [ OR ALTER ] FUNCTION [ schema_name. ] function_name   
> ( [ { @parameter_name [ AS ] [ type_schema_name. ] parameter_data_type   
>     [ = default ] [ READONLY ] }   
>     [ ,...n ]  
>   ]  
> )  
> RETURNS TABLE  
>     [ WITH <function_option> [ ,...n ] ]  
>     [ AS ]  
>     RETURN [ ( ] select_stmt [ ) ]  
> [ ; ]
> ```

This is an **inline** TVF. As the syntax shows, it can include solely a `RETURN` followed by a `SELECT`. Nothing more, nothing less.

> ```
> -- Transact-SQL Multi-Statement Table-Valued Function Syntax  
> CREATE [ OR ALTER ] FUNCTION [ schema_name. ] function_name   
> ( [ { @parameter_name [ AS ] [ type_schema_name. ] parameter_data_type   
>     [ = default ] [READONLY] }   
>     [ ,...n ]  
>   ]  
> )  
> RETURNS @return_variable TABLE <table_type_definition>  
>     [ WITH <function_option> [ ,...n ] ]  
>     [ AS ]  
>     BEGIN   
>         function_body   
>         RETURN  
>     END  
> [ ; ]
> ```

This is a **multi-statement** TVF. As the name suggests, you can include *multiple* statements in the definition. But note that you *must* specify the schema of the returned table as part of the function definitions.